# How do I solve labor scheduling problem based on different constraints?

Tags: resource-scheduling, or-tools

Schedule labors for the given task, based on different constraints.
Constraints examples are labor Skills, time, locations, shifts, holidays, priorities, capacity, etc.

Problem description:
Let us say there is a task to set up the Linux server in California on 25th Dec and to set up the server, it takes 5 hours of time. To set up a Linus server we would need labor who is skilled with the Linux server and stays in California and should be free on 25th Dec from 9 am - 3 pm. total six hours.

So if there is a pool of labor resources and if I have to find suitable labors for multiple tasks, What approach should I follow?

I google and found that this is a constraint-based programming problem and google OR Tools and other models provide a way to solve it.

So I started looking into [Google OR Tools](https://developers.google.com/optimization/introduction/overview) Google OR Tools doc.
The documentation provides basic examples.

I found another doc on git hub for google OR which better than the above link.
[Git hub doc for google OR Tools](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/doc/README.md)

I tried implementing the nurse scheduling program which given here [Google OR nurse scheduling](https://developers.google.com/optimization/scheduling/employee_scheduling)

I am having difficulty in understanding the program. It is not that I am having difficulty in understanding python or java.

So my questions are.

What are the way of solving such a problem?
Is Google OR is the right tool? If yes, What are the prerequisite for google OR if somebody has weak maths background? 
How should I proceed to solve such a problem?

Comment: Could you be more detailed about your problem?